# Windows 10 - Copy files asks to overwrite files

Tags: windows-10, copy-paste

Whenever I copy large amount of files, lets say my Windows user folder, to a new location, at one point I'm prompted if I want to overwrite the duplicates in that are already in the destination.

There shouldn't be any files in any duplicate files in any case, so what exactly is Windows doing here, why does the Windows Explorer gets confused?

Comment: Have you checked if the files in question aren't hidden? If so, Windows Explorer would know they're there, even though you can't see them, and would warn you. Can you post a screenshot of the warning window?

Comment: It's this dialog: https://i2.wp.com/www.nextofwindows.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Replace-or-Skip-Files-2017-07-30-22_12_56.png

It's set to show hidden and system files.

Comment: Can you try to reboot your PC in Safe Mode and try to copy the same files again, in the exact same conditions (same origin folder, same destination folder, same files)? Could be that the files you're trying to copy to another location are read-only, and can't be moved without a warning (improbable, but plausible). You're using the regular drag-and-drop, not the "robocopy" command in command line?

Comment: Can't reboot that PC atm, but the error is reproducible by copying the same files to a new location.
I used just copy and paste from within the Windows Explorer

Comment: When in doubt, Yes to all.

Comment: I agree. If those files are indeed already in the target location, overwriting them will ensure no data loss, unless you replace same-name files with a different, less up-to-date version, but if they're not visible, they're probably not there at all. Could be that those files have been deleted, but are still considered as present, for some reason. Is the target location a USB drive, or SD Card? File deletion in exFAT isn't handled the same way it is in NTFS or FAT32, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to say that this also just happened to me when copying many files at once. The files were DEFINITELY NOT there before: The destination was a newly created folder.

Comment: Hi Keith, this would be more appropriate as a comment attached to the question and not an answer. Welcome to Super User!